# Jenkins - Error when deploying EAR to IBM WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins, continuous-integration, websphere

(Updated as of 8 May 2018)

This is about an issue experienced during the connection phase when deploying EAR to WebSphere Application Server in Jenkins using the "WebSphere Deployer Plugin".

System information:

[Jenkins]
Jenkins version: 2.107.2
java.runtime.version (as seen from Jenkins Admin UI): 1.8.0_144-b01

[Jenkins - WebSphere Deployer Plugin]
**Version: 1.6.1

Copied the relevant JAR files (from C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\runtimes and C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins) to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\websphere-deployer\WEB-INF\lib.

Cell/Node/Server info is specified in the plugin configuration (same as what is shown in "Show Available Targets").**

[IBM WebSphere Application Server]
WAS version: 9.0.0.7
Java version: 1.8.0_151
Administrative security: Enabled
Application security: Disabled
SOAP connection port: 8880 (checked to be not being blocked by firewall)
Telnet to port 8880 is successful
Command line login to wsadmin via port 8880 is successful

The "Test Connection" is successful. Unfortunately, in the actual job run the deploy phase still fails at connection.

The relevant log information is as follows

[**Jenkins console log / job log (displayed in the Jenkins Admin UI "Console Output")**]

> 12:48:31 Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...
>  12:48:31
>   The following artifacts will be deployed in this order...
>  12:48:31
>   -------------------------------------------
>  12:48:36 *[EAR file path]*
>   Last modified on May 08, 2018 12:47:56
>  12:48:36
>   -------------------------------------------
>  12:48:59 Artifact is being deployed to virtual host: default_host
>  12:49:08 Error deploying to IBM
>   WebSphere Application Server: Could not determine if artifact
>   '*[App name]*' is installed: AdminException:
>   12:49:08 Performing
>   rollback of '*[App name]*'
>  12:49:08 WARNING: Artifact doesn't exist
>   rollback repository
>  12:49:08 Build step 'Deploy To IBM WebSphere
>   Application Server' changed build result to FAILURE
>  12:49:12 Finished:
>   FAILURE

[**Jenkins error log (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.err.log)**]

> May 08, 2018 12:43:47 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
>  INFO: Jenkins is
>   fully up and running
>  May 08, 2018 12:43:53 PM
>   javax.jmdns.impl.DNSStatefulObject$DefaultImplementation
>   waitForAnnounced WARNING: Wait for announced timed out: DNS:
>   *[Host name]*. state: announcing 2 task: Announcer(*[Host name]*)
>   state: announcing
>  2 May 08, 2018 12:45:52 PM
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory
>  WARNING: ADMC0046W:
>   The system failed to load properties from com.ibm.SOAP.configURL:
>   file:null/properties/soap.client.props
>  May 08, 2018 12:45:54 PM
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager
>  INFO: CWPKI0051I: The process
>   has the java security property jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms set to
>   [MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, RSA keySize < 1024, DSA
>   keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224].  The WebSphere Application server
>   is setting the java security property jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms
>   to [MD2, RSA keySize < 1024, MD5].
>   May 08, 2018 12:45:54 PM
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager
>  INFO: CWPKI0051I: The process
>   has the java security property jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms set to
>   [SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224].  The
>   WebSphere Application server is setting the java security property
>   jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms to [SSLv3, RC4, DH keySize < 768,
>   MD5withRSA].
>   May 08, 2018 12:45:54 PM
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.SSLConfigManager
>  INFO: CWPKI0027I: Disabling
>   default hostname verification for HTTPS URL connections.
>  May 08, 2018
>   12:45:54 PM com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator
>  INFO:
>   CWSCF0002I: The client code is attempting to load the security
>   configuration the server and this operation is not allowed.
>  May 08,
>   2018 12:45:56 PM com.ibm.ws.security.config.SecurityObjectLocator
>   INFO: CWSCF0002I: The client code is attempting to load the security
>   configuration the server and this operation is not allowed.
>  May 08,
>   2018 12:46:06 PM com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory
>   WARNING: ADMC0046W: The system failed to load properties from
>   com.ibm.SOAP.configURL: file:null/properties/soap.client.props
>  May 08,
>   2018 12:46:32 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.WebhookManager$1
>   run
>  INFO: GitHub webhooks activated for job *[Jenkins Job name]* with
>   [GitHubRepositoryName[host=github.com,username=*[GitHub user name]*,repository=*[GitHub repository]*]]
>   (events: [PUSH])
>  May 08, 2018 12:46:37 PM
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform
>   getSelectedProtocol
>  INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are
>   disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?
>  May 08, 2018 12:48:31
>   PM hudson.model.Run execute INFO: *[Jenkins Job name]* #38 main build action completed: SUCCESS
>  May
>   08, 2018 12:48:31 PM com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory
>   WARNING: ADMC0046W: The system failed to load properties from
>   com.ibm.SOAP.configURL: file:null/properties/soap.client.props
>  May 08,
>   2018 12:48:50 PM
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform
>   getSelectedProtocol
>  INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are
>   disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException:
>    at
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementProxy.proxyInvoke(AppManagementProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementProxy.checkIfAppExists(AppManagementProxy.java:269)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere.services.deployment.WebSphereDeploymentService.isArtifactInstalled(WebSphereDeploymentService.java:468)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.stopArtifact(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:409)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:245)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
>     at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1752)
>      at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
>    at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
>  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
>    at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl.invoke(AdminClientImpl.java:224)
>     at
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppManagementProxy.proxyInvoke(AppManagementProxy.java:186)
>     ... 13 more
>  Caused by: [SOAPException:
>   faultCode=SOAP-ENV:ServerException; msg=The Soap RPC call can't
>   be unmarshalled.]
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.handleAdminFault(SOAPConnectorClient.java:959)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplateOnce(SOAPConnectorClient.java:924)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:689)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:679)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:665)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:487)
>     ... 16 more

[**WAS console log (SystemOut.log) (C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\SystemOut.log)**]

> [5/8/18 12:49:00:183 CST] 000000f7 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E:
>   Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is
>   com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.PasswordCheckFailedException:
>   CWWIM4513E  The password match failed for the 'WASadmin' principal
>   name..
>  [5/8/18 12:49:00:332 CST] 000000f6 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E:
>   Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is
>   com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.PasswordCheckFailedException:
>   CWWIM4513E  The password match failed for the 'WASadmin' principal
>   name..
>  [5/8/18 12:49:04:291 CST] 000000f7 LTPAServerObj E   SECJ0369E:
>   Authentication failed when using LTPA. The exception is
>   com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.PasswordCheckFailedException:
>   CWWIM4513E  The password match failed for the 'WASadmin' principal
>   name..
>  [5/8/18 12:49:07:221 CST] 000000f7 FFDCJanitor   I
>   com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FFDCJanitor doCleanupIfNeeded FFDC0004I: FFDC log
>   file management removed 20 of 20 files that have reached their
>   configured maximum age
>  [5/8/18 12:49:07:486 CST] 000000f7 FfdcProvider
>   W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC
>   Incident emitted on
>   C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_f7987cd2_18.05.08_12.49.07.2212966399582449208005.txt
>   Unable to authenticate incoming request 534
>  [5/8/18 12:49:07:489 CST]
>   000000f7 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident
>   FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on
>   C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_f7987cd2_18.05.08_12.49.07.4884954440341702141044.txt
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPUtils.extractSoapCall 157
>   [5/8/18 12:49:07:716 CST] 000000f7 FfdcProvider  W
>   com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident
>   emitted on
>   C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_f7987cd2_18.05.08_12.49.07.4909017290418303421157.txt
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service 212

Comment: `NoSuchAlgorithmException` - looks like SSL misconfiguration. Try to configure your Jenkins JVM for TLS, and check SSL settings on your WebSphere.

Comment: The plugin bypasses the com.ibm.SOAP.configURL environment variable. This is to simplify the configuration so you don't have to include the soap.client.props or the ssl.client.props or the tmjx jar. They are not needed and can be ignored because the plugin directly sets the values it needs internally.

Comment: @Patrick C: Have you resolved this error ? I also got this problem

Answer (score 0):

Just released v1.5.6, please try upgrading to this version. You won't have to deal with certificates anymore if you select the following option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I followed the suggestion, but no luck...
Wonder if it is that the SSL certs are ok, but some other config is incorrect.

Comment: Just published v1.6.0 to try to address this issue. Be sure to follow the updated configuration specs. Secondly, I would update to WAS v9.0.0.7. After you update WAS, you MUST copy over the updated jars in the /runtimes & /plugins (see documentation) to your websphere-deployer/WEB-INF/lib folder. Keep me posted

Comment: Have updated the WebSphere Deployer Plugin and WAS as per advice, but still face the issue. Relevant details as per above, thanks.

Comment: @PatrickC. Just published fix for null pointer. Update the thread a appropriate so this issue can be tracked down. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @PatrickC. In your screenshot, you seem to have the default "deployment target". You need to replace this with the value you get back from the "Show available targets". The default value in the "deployment target" setting is just used as a placeholder

Comment: thanks. Updated the plugin and specified the cell/node/server info, but still had issues.

Comment: @PatrickC. Are you using LTPA for authentication to WAS? Is so, the plugin can only support basic authentication using the jenkins job configuration

Comment: In the WAS admin console, under "Security" > "Global Security", I see there are 3  authentication mechanisms available, which are "LTPA", "Kerberos and LTPA" and "SWAM (deprecated)". Do you mean the SWAM one? I tried with SWAM but and the error is the same.